# How can I stop my iPhone displaying "iCloud Backup requires that you verify your password" repeatedly?

Tags: iphone, backup, icloud

Due to what turned out to be a (I assume unrelated) sim card problem, I recently wiped my iPhone 4, and then reinstalled from a backup.

Since then, multiple times per day, my iPhone displays a "iCloud Backup requires that you verify your password" message, and then prompts for my iCloud password. If the correct password is entered, the prompt is dismissed, only to return after a few hours (I've not noticed any specific triggering action I'm performing).

How can I stop this prompt from appearing repeatedly?

Presumably disabling the iCloud backup, as suggested at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3406796 would do the trick, but I do still want the backup enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I personally had this same message. I turned off iCloud backups, then turned it back on. Settings > iCloud > Backup. While it did ask for my password the first time, it has not asked since.

If that doesn't work, I suggest to again, turn off iCloud backup, delete the backup, then turn it back on.

1. Settings > iCloud > Backup, turn off.
2. Settings > iCloud > Storage >
   Manage Storage, locate the backup, tap edit in the top corner, and
   delete.
3. Settings > iCloud > Backup, turn on.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it off, but then you wouldn't be able to backup.
If you have a Mac or PC, iTunes installed, your lightning or 30-pin dock connecter cable, a resonable amount of free space, you can backup with iTunes. It won't nag you. Plug in your iPhone, open iTunes, click your iPhone, and scroll to where it says backups, click iTunes, you can backup Health and HomeKit data, and click backup now! If it still nags you about iCloud later do this, go to Settings>iCloud>Backup, and turn it off.

Comment: That works, but he did say he wanted to still use *iCloud* backups.

Answer (score -2):

If you delete your iCloud account and start a new one it should work again.

Comment: Do you propose to log out and in again, or to really delete the account and setup a new one with a different name/ID?

Comment: Really delete the iCloud account and start a new one with diffrence email

Comment: There are two problems with this "solution" 1) many people can't walk away from purchase history and email and/or the simplicity of one account for all iCloud activities just because a certificate is wrong (or a date is wrong) 2) It's at best a workaround and no cure is found in case it happens again.